# Why should these two functions approximate each other so well?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

I am a physicist and during some of my research I realized that $\log_2 \sec(\pi x)$ is *really well* approximated by $\frac{6x^2}{1-x}$ for small but positive $x$. Is there any reason this should be so? After all the former function looks quite unwieldy on first sight. In particular, I am wondering whether there is some context in mathematics where these functions would arise, with the hope of understanding why they should agree so well. (Note that if I instead simply Taylor expand the former function and keep the leading term, it performs much more poorly.)

EDIT: Here is a plot from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20log_2%20sec(pi*x)%20and%206x%5E2%2F(1-x)%20from%20x%20%3D%200%20to%20x%20%3D%20.5):

[image: Plot of log_2(sec(pi x)) and 6x^2/(1-x)]

Note that at $x= \frac{1}{2}$, the former function has a singularity.

Edit: There were comments about the Taylor series and Padé approximants at $0$. The approximation is neither, and it is not exceptional at $0$, but it seems good on the interval $[0,1/3]$.

[image: Plot of difference between 0 and 1/3]

Comment: I do not see that this approximation is particularly good, nor is any reason given here.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Fair enough, I have added a plot to illustrate the point.

Comment: Take the difference of the two functions and see the graph. You'll see something opposite to your initial speculation.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the close votes. Isn't it a genuine question to ask why I can approximate such a complicated function by such a simple function, considering that the answer is not just a simple consequence of Taylor expansion?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Thanks for the comment. The difference to me looks pretty good, actually. Or are you looking at the relative difference (i.e. dividing by the function itself)?

Comment: I retracted my close vote. I thought this would just be a Padé approximant, but it is not the degree-$(2,1)$ approximant $\frac{\pi^2 x^2}{2 \log 2}$. Instead, this reminds me of a least-squares approximation with respect to some measure, which is not the closest possible at $0$ but which stays small for a long time.

Comment: Let $f(x)=\log_2(\sec(\pi x)), g(x)=\frac{6x^2}{1-x}$ and $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Then it appears that $h(10^{-a})\approx 10^{-2a}$.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: Yes, you can read that from the Taylor series which disagree on the second term, $6x^2$ vs. $7.12x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat better rational approximation for your function with the same degrees of numerator and denominator on the interval $[0, 0.35]$ is
$$ \frac{-0.003425070267307+(.24505402726368+6.15039272385520 x) x}{1.26465060967883-1.51228919816475 x}$$
(obtained using the Remez algorithm in Maple).  Here is a plot of the differences between $\log_2(\sec(\pi x))$ and these approximations (mine in red, yours in blue).

[image]

Comment: Remez minimizes the supremum of the difference, right? Is there something similar that would let you set the difference to be $0$ at $0$ and $1/3$ and minimize the integral of the square of the differences with respect to some measure?